# How to recover data after namenode -format command in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am using hadoop 1.2.1 version. due to some unknown reason, my namenode goes down and following log information was obtained

```
2017-07-28 15:04:47,422 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Start loading image file /home/hpcnl/crawler/hadoop-1.2.1/tmp/dfs/name/current/fsimage
2017-07-28 15:04:47,423 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:834)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
2017-07-28 15:04:47,428 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:881)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:834)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:427)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:395)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1479)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1488)
```

Then I search on internet and found that you should stop cluster and run following command

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

After this when I restart cluster, data was not appeared in respective folders in HDFS. Can I recover my data? How to handle such situations in future if my namenode goes down?

Comment: Might be of interest: [Hadoop backup and recovery tool and guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234067/hadoop-backup-and-recovery-tool-and-guidance)

Answer (score 0):

You can always backup your metadata by using these commands:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode enter
hdfs dfsadmin -saveNamespace
```

---

These commands will put your namenode in safemode and push the edits to the FSImage file:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -fetchImage /path/someFilename
```

*or*

```
cd /namenode/data/current/
tar -cvf /root/nn_backup_data.tar
```

---

Now you can place this data in your namenode metadata directory and restart the namenode.

Please note that you shouldn't use the command below until unless you don't have any other options:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```